# JHipster and Java 10

Tags: jhipster

can I use Java 10 and JHipster (from which release version on)?

We have built our JHipster application with Java 8 at one point in time, with JHipster 4.13.3.
Can we now simply use our JHipster application with Java 10, or is some migration effort needed? Would it be enough to specify in the pom.xml

```
<java.version>1.8</java.version>
```

Also, will it work out using JHipster (probably the latest release 4.14.3 or later) and Java 10 to generate a new JHipster application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JHipster 5 will be compatible with Java 10. <strike>Concerning JHipster 4.14.3, in the `pom.xml`, if you modify the `<requireJavaVersion>` rule in addition of `<java.version>` to accept Java 10, it should work. Haven't tested it though.</strike>

EDIT

As Gaël Marziou pointed out, JHipster 4.14.3 is using Spring Boot 1 and hence is not compatible with Java 10.

Comment: I thought you needed Spring Boot 2 and so JHipster 5.

Comment: You're right, I forgot about that. JHipster has always been using with Spring Boot 2 for me.. I gonna edit the post.